# Javascript how to stop form from submitting

Tags: javascript, java

anyone has any ideas how to stop jsp pages from submitting? I'm using java spring 2.0. And I'm using form controller, so when i click the submit button then it goes to the validation method.

here the submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="_target" value="Next" onClick="next()"
```

My plan is, i put the confirmation in my javascript, if confirm is 'OK' then it will do nothing. But at my current situation, it always goes to validae controller immediately.

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Please show all relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This basically should return true or false from the confirm box and then take it to the validation function. Could you please try it by yourself because I'm not pretty confident about this.

```
<input type="submit" name="_target" value="Next" onClick="next();return confirm("Are you sure?");">
```

Comment: thankyou this works. by add return in the onClick, it will stop the submission if the return is false

Comment: Nice! glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

just change the input `type` to anything other than `submit` or,

you can pass event into your next function such as:

```
<input type="submit" name="_target" value="Next" onClick="next(event)" 

function next(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    // rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the button type from submit to button. Call your validation in onClick(), and if the input is validated, submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("formid").submit(function(e){

    return false;


    //or


    e.preventDefault();

)};
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use a function in the form:

```
<form action="some_url" onsubmit="return confirm('Are You Sure?')" ... >

  <input type="submit" name="_target" value="Next">  

</form>
```

Some similar if you are using the `spring-form.tld` tag library.